# PHP: String replace with Regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Ive tried to get the Regex to work for this script.

What I need it to do is take the width and height from the youtube code that is inserted and replace it with a specified height and width.

```
$youtube = str_replace('width="' * ' "','width="500"' $_POST['youtube']);
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: 1) show php code to display youtube, 2) show what have you tried

Comment: I did add code, the < ? php tags edited it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code is:

```
$code = 'width="100" and height="200"';
```

And then perform the below regex replace using `preg_replace()`

```
$code = preg_replace('/width="\d+"/', 'width="XXX"', $code);
$code = preg_replace('/height="\d+"/', 'height="XXX"', $code);
```

`\d+` means any number of digit starting from length one.